# mysql update multiple records of multiple tables using one statement based on condition

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-update

I have a mysql table for keeping record of two person competitions like this:

```
- gameid
- id1 // id of player 1
- id2 // id of player 2
- score1 // score of player 1
- score2 // score of player 2
- state // state of the games is initially 0, then the score updates are made and in order to prevent further updates the state must be updated to 1
```

I need to check the records and update another table "users" based on the scores. ex:
if **score1 > score2** I need to update 3 things:

```
1- the state of the game // from 0 to 1
2- in table "users" add 1 point to the column score for the user with userid = id1
2- in table "users" subtract 1 point from the column score for the user with userid = id2
```

So far I am able to update 1 and 2 but I need all the 3 updates in one command:

```
UPDATE dbo.games AS GA , dbo.users AS US 
SET GA.state = 1, US.score = US.score + 1
WHERE US.id = GA.id1 AND GA.state = 0 and GA.score1 > GA.score2
```

I can separate the **+1** and **-1** commands, it will work fine. But when the command is run, both users' scores should be updated. Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you write a SELECT that returns the equivalent result?

Comment: And confirm your RDBMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
update dbo.games as ga, dbo.users as us
set 
    ga.state = 1, 
    us1.score = us1.score + case 
        when 
            (ga.score1 > ga.score2 and us.id = ga1.id1)
            or (ga.score2 > ga.score1 and us.id = ga2.id2)
        then 1
        else -1
    end
where 
    ga.state = 0 
    and ga.score1 <> ga.score2
    and us.id in (ga.id1, ga.id2)
```

The logic is to select *two rows* in the user table, and then do conditional logic to decide whether to add or remove a point.

Note: you did not tell how you want to handle tied competitions - so this query explicitly ignores them.

Comment: Thank you, I get the error: **#1690 - BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range** , But if I change -1 to 0 it works fine.

Comment: I changed the line to ELSE (case when us.score >= 1 then -1 ELSE 0 END) and everything works like a charm. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE dbo.games AS GA , dbo.users AS US     
SET GA.state = 1, (CASE WHEN US.id =GA.id1 THEN US.score = US.score + 1
 ELSE WHEN US.id=id2 THEN US.score =US.score-1 END)  
WHERE  GA.state = 0 and GA.score1 > GA.score2
```

This query increments score with 1 when US.id=id1 and decrements score with 1 when US.id =id2